# Prevent reload after submission

Tags: php, jquery

I am using follwing code but it does not prevent to reload and successful text is not seen on form page.

```
$("#ak_Submit_img").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#ak").attr("action"), 
         $("#ak :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
   });
 clearInput();
});

$("#ak").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});

function clearInput() {
    $("#ak :input").each( function() {
       $(this).val('');
    });
} 

<form id='ak' class='sfm_form' method='post' action='such.php' accept-charset='UTF-8'>

<input type='image' name='Submit' id='ak_Submit_img' src='images/ak-Submit-0.png' alt='submit'/>
```

Where am I making mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`return false` is not the way to prevent reload with jquery.

The usual way to prevent a reload from a button press is:

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
  // do whatever actions you need here
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

For your code i would suggest:

```
$("#ak_Submit_img").click( function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $.post( $("#ak").attr("action"), 
         $("#ak :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
   });
 clearInput();
});
```

**OR**

```
$("#ak").submit( function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  return false; 
});
```

Comment: that may be as the event being prevented is on the wrong part. Looking at it again, you submit the form in its own function. Try using the `e.preventDefault();` on the submit function.

Comment: I have added the instance in my answer

Comment: can you put it together in a JSfiddle as it works currently please.